# How to extract the first rows that have a unique value in specific column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, sorting

The unique items in D are: 4,3,2.

[image: asd]

I wish to extract 3 rows for each D value, For each row, provide the first row that this D value appears.

I tried using `=query` but it doesn't support grouping or subqueries. I tried to use `arrayformula` but it doesn't support the `query` function.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can try **`SORTN`** with **`2`** as 3rd parameter:

  ```
  =SORTN(E1:I, ROWS(E:E), 2, 2, 1)
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: You're the king of the universe! Thanks.